# Given 2 conditionally independent positive tests for a disease, what is the probability the tested person has the disease?

Tags: statistics

So if someone was to get tested for a disease denoted by A and had two tests done the first denoted by B and the second by C, if you get positive test results for both how do you translate the two conditionally independent test results to a probability of being positive for the disease P(A|B,C)?

Assuming you have the following available to you:

P(A),
P(B),
P(C),
P(A|B),
P(A|C),
P(Not A|B),
P(Not A|C),
P(A| Not B),
P(A| Not C)

and A,B,C are binary...

Would the same methodology apply when trying to solve for
1 whether or not the patient is positive given both tests are negative P(A| Not B, Not C)
2 whether or not the patient is negative given 2 positive tests P(Not A|B, C)

I think my issues with this stems from last being in varsity several years ago so I'm more then a little rusty and a somewhat flawed understanding of what "Conditional independence" means in this case.

Comment: You can reason it out.  In the 1st question, for the patient to be healthy, you must have both [$(\neg A)$ and $(B)$] as well as [$(\neg A)$ and $(C)$]. Given that events $(B)$ and $(C)$ have occurred, the chance of (still) being healthy is $Q = (\neg A | B) \times (\neg A|C).$  Then, the chance of being sick is 
$P = (1 - Q).$

Comment: By the way, the previous comment is wrong.  I left it intact as an example of my going off the rails.  [Bayes Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) kicks in.  The actual probability of still being healthy is $$\frac{(\neg A|B) \times (\neg A|C)}{[(\neg A|B) \times (\neg A|C)] + [(A|B) \times (A|C)]}.$$  The idea is that since you are given that events $(B)$ and $(C)$ have occurred, the denominator represents the two distinct ways that this might have occurred: either $(A)$ or $(\neg A)$.

Comment: Think of conditional independence this way:  Presumably the two tests aren't actually independent.  Their results are strongly linked to the underlying Reality.  However, the tests are not perfect.  Imagine that each test flawlessly detects the disease (or its absence) but that the test distorts the result with some probability (which may be different for the two tests, and which may be different for false negatives and false positives).  Saying that the tests are conditionally independent says that the two distortions are independent events.  ....

Comment: ....Thus getting two positives means either that the patient has the disease and the two tests independently reported accurate results, or that the patient does not have the disease but both tests distorted the result and reported false positives.